# How should I correct this priority_queue comparison function?

Tags: c++, c++11

With a number array nums, I'd like to sort the unique numbers by the frequency of their occurrences. The compiler is complaining about passing the unordered_map as 'this' argument discards qualifiers. How do I fix this?

```
    void sortByFreq(const vector<int>& nums) {
      unordered_map<int, int> counts;
      for (auto i: nums) ++counts[i];
      auto byCount = [counts](const int& a, const int& b) { return counts[a] > counts[b]; };
      priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(byCount)> minFreq(byCount);
      for (auto& kv: counts) {
        minFreq.push(kv.first);
      }
      ......
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you there is a `priority_queue`? Looks like we missing some information.

There are couple ways to fix issue with `counts` and lambda:

- use `at` instead `operator[]` - IMO best solution
- capture `counts` by reference
- make lambda mutable (I don't like this one)

From what you have described this should do the job:

```cpp
vector<int> sortedByFreq(const vector<int>& nums)
{
    unordered_map<int, int> counts;
    for (auto i : nums)
        ++counts[i];

    vector<int> result = nums;
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end(),
              [counts](auto a, auto b) {
                  return counts.at(a) > counts.at(b);
              });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: My code wasn't complete. I needed the heap to throw out less frequently occurred numbers and only keep the top K of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) `mutable`, to allow the non-const member function to be called on the copy-captured `counts`. (Note that the [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)  of `std::unordered_map` is a non-const member function, which will perform insertion if the key does not exist.)

> mutable: allows body to modify the parameters captured by copy, and to call their non-const member functions

e.g.

```
auto byCount = [counts](const int& a, const int& b) mutable { return counts[a] > counts[b]; };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at` instead of `operator[]`, as it has a `const` qualified overload.

```
auto byCount = [counts](const int& a, const int& b) { return counts.at(a) > counts.at(b); };
```